# problemas al Calcular promedio de notas php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7

*Estimados amigos un saludo cordial*, espero su ayuda.
Este es mi problema, al momento de registrar el primer curso de ciencias funciona muy bien, ahora al momento de poder llenar las notas del curso  de matematica automaticamente me sale el promedio debo llenar las notas en 6 cursos distintos, si me pueden ayudar a solucionar por favor.

[image: Cuento con la siguiente tabla]

Aqui tengo mi select para poder llenar las notas por cada materia cuando ingreso a llenar las notas me sale automaticamente los promedios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es de la primera area ciencia tecnologia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es de la segunda area Matematica  me debe mostrar por cada curso su promedio de manera independiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui les dejo el codigo por favor para guardar las notas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require 'functions.php';
//consulta las materias
$tb_miperu_materias = $conn->prepare("select * from tb_miperu_materias");
$tb_miperu_materias->execute();
$tb_miperu_materias = $tb_miperu_materias->fetchAll();

//consulta de grados
$tb_miperu_grados = $conn->prepare("select * from tb_miperu_grados");
$tb_miperu_grados->execute();
$tb_miperu_grados = $tb_miperu_grados->fetchAll();



//consulta las secciones
$tb_miperu_secciones = $conn->prepare("select * from tb_miperu_secciones");
$tb_miperu_secciones->execute();
$tb_miperu_secciones = $tb_miperu_secciones->fetchAll();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Notas | Registro de Notas</title>
       </head>
<body>

<div class="body">
    <div class="panel">
            <h3>Registro y Modificaci贸n Notas</h3>
           <?php
           if(!isset($_GET['revisar'])){
               ?>

            <form method="get" class="form" action="notas.view.php">
                <label>Seleccione el Grado</label><br>
                <select name="grado" required>
                    <?php foreach ($tb_miperu_grados as $grado):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $grado['id'] ?>"><?php echo $grado['nombregrado'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label>Seleccione la Materia</label><br>
                <select name="materia" required>
                    <?php foreach ($tb_miperu_materias as $materia):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $materia['id'] ?>"><?php echo $materia['nombre'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>

                <br><br>
                <label>Seleccione la Secci贸n</label><br>

                <select name="seccion" required>
                    <?php foreach ($tb_miperu_secciones as $seccion):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $seccion['id'] ?>"><?php echo $seccion['descripcion'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>


                <br><br>
                <button type="submit" name="revisar" value="1">Ingresar Notas</button> <a class="btn-link" href="listadonotas.view.php">Consultar Notas</a>
                <br><br>
            </form>
        <?php
           }
        ?>
        <hr>

        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['revisar'])){
            $id_materia = $_GET['materia'];
            $id_grado = $_GET['grado'];
            $id_seccion = $_GET['seccion'];

            //extrayendo el numero de evaluaciones para esa materia seleccionada
            $num_eval = $conn->prepare("SELECT num_evaluaciones 
                                                FROM tb_miperu_materias 
                                                WHERE id = ".$id_materia);
            $num_eval->execute();
            $num_eval = $num_eval->fetch();
            $num_eval = $num_eval['num_evaluaciones'];


            //mostrando el cuadro de notas de todos los alumnos del grado seleccionado
            $sqlalumnos = $conn->prepare("SELECT a.id, a.dni, a.num_lista, a.apellido_paterno, a.apellido_materno, a.nombres, 
                                                 b.nota, avg(b.nota) AS promedio, b.observaciones 
                                                 FROM tb_miperu_alumnos AS a LEFT JOIN tb_miperu_notas as b on a.id = b.id_alumno
                                                 WHERE id_grado = ".$id_grado." AND id_seccion = ".$id_seccion." group by a.id");
            $sqlalumnos->execute();
            $alumnos = $sqlalumnos->fetchAll();
            $num_alumnos = $sqlalumnos->rowCount();

            ?>
            <br>
            <a href="notas.view.php"><strong><< Volver</strong></a>
            <br>
            <br>
                          
                <form action="procesarnota.php" method="post">

            <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 13px;">


                <tr>
                    <th >NRO</th>
                    <th >CODIGO</th>
                    <th >APELLIDOS Y NOMBRES</th>
                    <th >TA</th>
                    <th >EP</th>
                    <th >EF</th>
                    <th >ES</th>

                       <!--  <?php
                        for($i = 1; $i <= $num_eval; $i++){
                            echo '<th>Nota '.$i .'</th>';
                        }
                        ?> -->
                    <th>PROMEDIO</th>                    
                    <th>OBS</th>
                    <th>Opciones</th>
                </tr>
                
                <?php foreach ($alumnos as $index => $alumno) :?>
                
                    <!-- campos ocultos necesarios para realizar el insert-->
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num_alumnos ?>" name="num_alumnos">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $alumno['id'] ?>" name="<?php echo 'id_alumno'.$index ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num_eval ?>" name="num_eval">
                     <!-- campos para devolver los parametros en el get y mantener los mismos datos al hacer el header location-->
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_materia ?>" name="id_materia">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_grado ?>" name="id_grado">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_seccion ?>" name="id_seccion">
                    <tr>
                        
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $alumno['num_lista'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $alumno['dni'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $alumno['apellido_paterno']." ".$alumno['apellido_materno'].", ".$alumno['nombres'] ?></td>
                        
                        <?php
                           if(existeNota($alumno['id'],$id_materia,$conn) > 0){
                                
                                //ya tiene notas registradas
                                $notas = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, nota 
                                                                FROM tb_miperu_notas 
                                                                WHERE id_alumno = ".$alumno['id']." 
                                                                  AND id_materia = ".$id_materia);
                                $notas->execute();
                                $registrosnotas = $notas->fetchAll();
                                $num_notas = $notas->rowCount();
                                
                                foreach ($registrosnotas as $eval => $nota){
                                    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$nota['id'].'" name="idnota' . $eval .'alumno' . $index . '">';
                                    echo '<td><input type="text" maxlength="5" value="'.$nota['nota'].'" name="evaluacion' . $eval . 'alumno' . $index . '" class="txtnota"></td>';
                                }
                                
                                if($num_eval > $num_notas){
                                    $dif = $num_eval - $num_notas;

                                    for($i = $num_notas; $i < $dif + $num_notas; $i++) {
                                        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$nota['id'].'" name="idnota' . $i .'alumno' . $index . '">';
                                        echo '<td><input type="text" maxlength="5" value="'.$nota['nota'].'" name="evaluacion' . $i . 'alumno' . $index . '" class="txtnota"></td>';
                                    }
                                }


                            }else {
                                //extrayendo el numero de evaluaciones para esa materia seleccionada
                                for($i = 0; $i < $num_eval; $i++) {
                                    echo '<td><input type="text" maxlength="5" name="evaluacion' . $i . 'alumno' . $index . '" class="txtnota"></td>';
                                }
                            }

                            echo '<td align="center">'.number_format($alumno['promedio'], 2).'</td>';

                            if(existeNota($alumno['id'],$id_materia,$conn) > 0){
                                echo '<td><input type="text" maxlength="100" value="'.$alumno['observaciones'].'" name="observaciones' . $index . '" class="txtnota"></td>';
                            }else {
                                echo '<td><input type="text" name="observaciones' . $index . '" class="txtnota"></td>';
                            }

                        if(existeNota($alumno['id'],$id_materia,$conn) > 0){
                            echo '<td><a href="notadelete.php?idalumno='.$alumno['id'].'&idmateria='.$id_materia.'">Eliminar</a> </td>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<td>Sin notas</td>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                
                <tr></tr>
                
            </table>
            
                <br>
                <button type="submit" name="insertar">Guardar</button> <button type="reset">Limpiar</button> 
                
                <a class="btn-link" href="listadonotas.view.php">Consultar Notas</a>
                
                <br>
            </form>


        <?php }

        ?>
                <!--mostrando los mensajes que recibe a traves de los parametros en la url-->
                <?php
                if(isset($_GET['err']))
                    echo '<span class="error">Error al almacenar el registro</span>';
                if(isset($_GET['info']))
                    echo '<span class="success">Registro almacenado correctamente!</span>';
                ?>

            </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['err']))
            echo '<span class="error">Error al guardar</span>';
        ?>
        </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

este ya tambien es para mostrar el listado de notas por  curso

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require 'functions.php';

//consulta las materias
$tb_miperu_materias = $conn->prepare("select * from tb_miperu_materias");
$tb_miperu_materias->execute();
$tb_miperu_materias = $tb_miperu_materias->fetchAll();

//consulta de grados
$tb_miperu_grados = $conn->prepare("select * from tb_miperu_grados");
$tb_miperu_grados->execute();
$tb_miperu_grados = $tb_miperu_grados->fetchAll();

//consulta las secciones
$tb_miperu_secciones = $conn->prepare("select * from tb_miperu_secciones");
$tb_miperu_secciones->execute();
$tb_miperu_secciones = $tb_miperu_secciones->fetchAll();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Notas | Registro de Notas</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="body">
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>Consulta de Notas</h3>
        <?php
        if(!isset($_GET['consultar'])){
            ?>
            <p>Seleccione el grado, la materia y la secci贸n</p>
            <form method="get" class="form" action="listadonotas.view.php">
                <label>Seleccione el Grado</label><br>
                <select name="grado" required>
                    <?php foreach ($tb_miperu_grados as $grado):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $grado['id'] ?>"><?php echo $grado['nombregrado'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label>Seleccione la Materia</label><br>
                <select name="materia" required>
                    <?php foreach ($tb_miperu_materias as $materia):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $materia['id'] ?>"><?php echo $materia['nombre'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>

                <br><br>
                <label>Seleccione la Secci贸n</label><br><br>

                <select name="seccion" required>
                    <?php foreach ($tb_miperu_secciones as $seccion):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $seccion['id'] ?>"><?php echo $seccion['descripcion'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>
                
                <br><br>
                <button type="submit" name="consultar" value="1">Consultar Notas</button></a>
                <br><br>
            </form>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <hr>

        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['consultar'])){
            $id_materia = $_GET['materia'];
            $id_grado = $_GET['grado'];
            $id_seccion = $_GET['seccion'];

            //extrayendo el numero de evaluaciones para esa materia seleccionada
            $num_eval = $conn->prepare("select num_evaluaciones 
                                        FROM tb_miperu_materias 
                                        where id = ".$id_materia);
            $num_eval->execute();
            $num_eval = $num_eval->fetch();
            $num_eval = $num_eval['num_evaluaciones'];


            //mostrando el cuadro de notas de todos los alumnos del grado seleccionado
            $sqlalumnos = $conn->prepare("SELECT a.id, a.dni, a.apellido_paterno, a.apellido_materno, a.nombres, 
                                          b.nota,b.observaciones, avg(b.nota) as promedio 
                                          FROM tb_miperu_alumnos AS a left join tb_miperu_notas as b on a.id = b.id_alumno
                                          WHERE id_grado = ".$id_grado." and id_seccion = ".$id_seccion." group by a.id");
            $sqlalumnos->execute();
            $alumnos = $sqlalumnos->fetchAll();
            $num_alumnos = $sqlalumnos->rowCount();
            $promediototal = 0.0;

            ?>
            <br>
            <a href="listadonotas.view.php"><strong><< Volver</strong></a>
            <br>
            <br>


                <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>NRO</th>
                        <th>CODIGO </th>
                        <th>APELLIDOS Y NOMBRES</th>
                        <th>TA</th>
                        <th>EP</th>
                        <th>EF</th>
                        <th>AV</th>
                        
                        <th>PROMEDIO</th>
                        <th>OBSERVACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($alumnos as $index => $alumno) :?>
                        <!-- campos ocultos necesarios para realizar el insert-->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><?php echo $alumno['num_lista'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $alumno['dni'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $alumno['apellido_paterno']." ".$alumno['apellido_materno'].", ".$alumno['nombres'] ?></td>
                            
                            <?php
                                //escribiendo las notas en columnas
                                $tb_miperu_notas = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, nota 
                                                                    FROM tb_miperu_notas 
                                                                    WHERE id_alumno = ".$alumno['id']." 
                                                                    AND id_materia = ".$id_materia);
                                $tb_miperu_notas->execute();
                                $tb_miperu_notas = $tb_miperu_notas->fetchAll();

                                foreach ($tb_miperu_notas as $eval => $nota) {

                                    echo '<td align="center"><input type="hidden" 
                                            name="nota'.$eval.'" value="'. $nota['nota'] . '" >'. $nota['nota'] . '</td>';

                                }

                            echo '<td align="center">'.number_format($alumno['promedio'], 2).'</td>';
                            
                            //echo '<td><a href="notas.view.php?grado='.$id_grado.'&materia='.$id_materia.'&seccion='.$id_seccion.'">Editar</a> </td>';
                            $promediototal += number_format($alumno['promedio'], 2);
                            
                            
                            echo '<td>'. $alumno['observaciones']. '</td>';
                            ?>

                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                    
                </table>

                <br>


        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: El group está por el id de alumno, así que el avg se calcula por alumno, no por alumno-curso.

Comment: Hola *Alfabravo* gracias, como haria para calcular el promedio

Comment: Dario, si quieres mostrar el promedio solo de las notas de esa materia, una opción es hacerlo inicializando la nota media para cada alumno (`$nota_media=0;` y dentro del `foreach ($tb_miperu_notas as $eval => $nota) {` Ahí podrías hacer un recorrido del array sumando por ejemplo 

`$nota_media += $nota['nota'];`

y en la línea donde la muestras, poner esa variable: 

`echo '<td align="center">'.number_format($nota_media, 2).'</td>';`

Comment: Muchas gracias por su gran apoyo saludos.